# Identity Server 4 in Docker using OIDC and Selenium Testing

Tags: docker, security, selenium-chromedriver, identityserver4

I am currently trying to run an integration test with Selenium on the following setup:

- IdentityServer4 hosted in a net core 3.1 REST service - running in its own docker container (securityservice)
- MVC Test Web User Interface running under net core 3.1 - running in its own docker container (testuserinterface)
- The selenium test is running on my local pc under a net core 3.1 test project

Where I am getting the issue is when i attempt to access a secure page on the Web Application the redirect is attempted to the identity server to show the user login page, however the url that the redirect is setup with id that of the docker container (e.g. http://securityservice/accouunt/login).  This url is not accessible from my local browser so my test is failing locally.

Is there a way that the login url can be customised (only for test purposes) to be that of the local machine and the locally exposed docker port (e.g. http://127.0.0.1:dockerport/account/login).

I have tried many different examples and combinations with currently no success.

Any help in this area would be most appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Stuart

Answer (score 0):

What I have done for local development and testing in some cases is to create a local HTTPS certificate using [mkcert](https://www.scottbrady91.com/ASPNET/Using-mkcert-for-ASPNET-Core-Development) and then in my local host file add an entry to map the domain of the certificate to 127.0.0.1

So I can use urls like https://identityservice:6001 to point to my IdentityServer.